# Error when saving configuration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-configuration, magento-2.0.7

I've been trying to add a `system.xml` configuration file to a Magento 2 module but I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor::shouldCloneFields() in /Users/mludd/Sites/magento2.pippin.pantburk/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php on line 211
```

From what I can tell the method `shouldCloneFields()` does in fact not exist in that class but the question I have is, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? The method seems to be declared in another class but I can't even seem to find the `Interceptor` class referenced in the error.

This is what my `system.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <!-- Add new Tab -->
        <tab id="dummymodule" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
            <label>DummyModule</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="dummymodule" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>DummyModule</label>
            <tab>dummymodule</tab> 
            <resource>Mludd_DummyModule::config_dummymodule</resource>

            <group id="first" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>First</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="second/id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Second</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error but my `system.xml` syntax was correct, so it was something else. Turns out it was the result of my cron_group being incorrectly configured, which caused errors when trying to save cron configuration under Configuration > Advanced > System.

It was fixed by adding this to my cron group:
`<use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>`

Comment: Thank you Jacco. I had this issue for a while after upgrading to Magento 2.1. This fix helped.

Comment: Thanks, Jacques your answer is helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was that there was a slash (`/`) in the second group's ID. Removed this and now it saves as intended.

No idea why I thought it would work to put a slash there.

Answer (score 1):

**group_id** should be unique in **system.xml** and **crontab.xml** files. It will solve this issue.

Thanks